# PCRE match a single character between curly braces

Tags: regex, pcre

I write a PCRE trying to match dollar signs (`$`) only if they are between the curly braces.

My example text is like that:

`Lorem $100 ipsum dolor {value$banana} sit $500 amet.`

The pattern `(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})` gives me everything between the curly braces (`{value$banana}`), but I need to exactly match the dollar sign in between. I do not need a pattern matching multiple occurrences.

I've been trying to work on this but could not find the answer anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to match a single `$` inside curly braces just once you may use

```
'~\{[^{}$]*\K\$(?=[^{}]*})~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XdLFas/1)

**Details**

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `[^{}$]*` - 0 or more chars other than `{`, `}` and `$`
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discarding all text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `(?=[^{}]*})` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Nice use of `\K` to avoid the variable width lookbehind +1.  Learn something new every day on this site.

Comment: Really Clean solution.